# Rendering a QGIS WMS layer in Firefox hogs the machine

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-server, apache

I am less than a novice beginner on GIS Systems and am groping for answers.

I followed instructions for WIN 7 Install at both
http://underdark.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/ and http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial#Windows

All appears to work well.  I can retrieve a capabilities-XML.

Next, I add an WMS Layer to a shapefile in QGIS.  Again, no issues.

Then I attempt to display via Firefox 18.0.2 with address call

> [http://localhost]/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&SRS=EPSG:4326&REQUEST=GetMap&map=C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/VA_VOTES_BUSINESS.qgs&BBOX=-36.215710,6.817432,-9.700450,58.551008&WIDTH=500&HEIGHT=1000&LAYERS=VA_VOTES_BUSINESS&FORMAT=image/png

The entire operating system becomes unstable at the page call.  Firefox displays `Connected to LocalHost`; there is 100% CPU usage (Pentium Dual Core 2.2 GHz); and 80% memory usage (4 GB).  I have to power off to regain control.

I see nothing but errors in the Apache error log but of course I'm not familiar with the references.  Spent 10 hours+ trying to troubleshoot and this is my last resort.  Any direction would be most helpful and appreciated.

QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa Desktop

Comment: Where do those brackets [] come from?

Comment: `VERSION=1.3.0&SRS=EPSG:4326&` this combination of parameters is incorrect.  As you have version 1.3.0 service you should use `CRS=EPSG:4326&`